# print statement including variable types

Tags: python, printing, formatting

I recently installed python and VSCode on a new mac and I'm getting some unexpected output when printing to the console with python that I wasn't seeing before.

Firstly When printing strings I'm getting u'(string) instead of the string itself. On my old computer I never saw this.

Secondly when printing an array Python prints array([ 51.55,  68.74,  89.89, 101.96]) instead of just [ 51.55,  68.74,  89.89, 101.96] like it would before.

Thirdly I'm noticing that it also prints to the console '\n' instead of actually printing a new line.

I couldn't find anything on here pertaining to this question other than using formatting for unicode strings. It's just weird that this never happened on my old computer but it happens now.

```
heights = [1.55, 1.74, 1.89, 1.96] #standard python list
weights = [50, 67, 88, 100]
np_heights = np.array(heights) 
np_weights = np.array(weights)
bmi = np_weights/np_heights**2 
print(bmi, "\n")
```

produces the output:

(array([20.81165453, 22.12973973, 24.63536855, 26.03082049]), '\n')

instead of:

[20.81165453, 22.12973973, 24.63536855, 26.03082049]

Comment: You're using Python 2 instead of Python 3

Comment: ive checked this with both python 2 and python 3 interpreters in vscode and it produces the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Change your print statement to:

`print bmi.__str__() + "\n"`   if you're using Python 2
or

`print(str(bmi) + "\n")`   if you're using Python 3

I think you're confusing the string concatenation character, using **,** instead of **+**